# How to create a team with template educationClass via Microsoft Graph with C#

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams, microsoft-graph-edu

I am trying without results to create a team in a educational tenant with **educationClass** template, dinamically with Microsoft Graph SDK for C#. This is the code with the BETA api that is recommended from the official website (https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/graph/api/team-post?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=csharp).

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var team = new Team
{
    DisplayName = "My Sample Team",
    Description = "My Sample Team’s Description",
    AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        {"template@odata.bind", "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teamsTemplates('educationClass')"},
        {"owners@odata.bind", "[\"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users('userId')\"]"}
    }
};

await graphClient.Teams
    .Request()
    .AddAsync(team);
```

When I execute this code it throws the following error: Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: 'Code: BadRequest
Message: Invalid URL format specified in @odata.bind for owners

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem. Instead of creating and array in a string as is recommended in the official page I used an external array of strings:

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );
string[] owners = new string[1];
owners[0] = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/userId";
var team = new Team
{
    DisplayName = "My Sample Team",
    Description = "My Sample Team’s Description",
    AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        {"template@odata.bind", "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teamsTemplates('educationClass')"},
        {"owners@odata.bind", owners}
    }
};

await graphClient.Teams
    .Request()
    .AddAsync(team);
```

Comment: Thank you! I was having trouble with this from using the official "array in a string" approach I kept finding everywhere, but only got past the syntax error using your approach shown here.